# NAs when using rnorm/rbinom/rweibull... with Shiny inputs inside

Tags: r, input, shiny, normal-distribution

I am having problems simulating data in my shiny app.

It is quite a large app, but what gives the problems is a specific part.
My app creates vectors of simulated data to then create a data frame.

For example, when working with rnorm the user introduces the mean and standard deviation.

A part of the server.R file would be something like this:

```
data <- reactive ({
 return( rnorm (10000, input$mean, input$sd)
 })
```

And then create the data frame. All the inputs are numericInput()

This works on the app (the simulated data is shown), but raises an error:

```
Error in rnorm(input$number_rows, input$mean, input$sd): invalid arguments
```

And the app ends up crashing in the end.

If I use as.numeric() on each of the inputs:

```
data <- reactive ({
 return( rnorm ( 10000, as.numeric(input$mean), as.numeric(input$sd))
 })
```

The error no longer appears, but I get a warning instead:

```
Warning in rnorm(n = 1e+05, as.numeric(input$mean), as.numeric(input$sd)): NAs produced
```

Apparently a vector is created, with length of 10000. But it is a vector only of NA values

Any idea on how to solve this, or why does this happen??

Thank you very much!

Comment: print out the values before you call `rnorm` so you can see what is wrong. You might need a `validate` statement in there to keep it from executing the first time through.

Comment: Perhaps if you give your `mean` and `sd` some default initial values they wouldn't be `NA`?